# How to use random_shuffle with CString?

Tags: c++, cstring, stdstring

I would like to shuffle the characters present in CString varible. How do i do it?
Std provide a finction called random_shuffle() which can be used to shuffle std::string in the following way
    std::string s("ThisIsSample");
    random_shuffle(s.first(),s.last());
But since CString doesnt have a function to access the fisrt and last character to iterate. How do i use random_shuffle with CString?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GetBuffer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa314880%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) to obtain the character buffer, and pass its boundaries to `std::random_shuffle`:

```
void shuffle_cstring(CString& c)
{
    size_t len = c.GetLength();
    LPTSTR buf = c.GetBuffer(1);
    std::random_shuffle(buf, buf + len);
    c.ReleaseBuffer();
}
```

Comment: You need to call [`ReleaseBuffer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300574%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) when you're done with your manipulations.

Comment: Oh, and you should also call `GetLength` first, and store the result in a separate variable. Because you're not supposed to call any other member functions on the `CString` between the time you call `GetBuffer` and the time you call `ReleaseBuffer`.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I wonder if that's really necessary in this case. MSDN says, *If you use the pointer returned by `GetBuffer` to change the string contents, you must call `ReleaseBuffer` before using any other CString member functions.* The code does change the contents, but only by rearranging characters, so it affects neither the length of the string nor the characters present.

Comment: A shuffle is a series of swaps. A swap is 3 assignments (1 to an external character, and 2 to elements in the array). And an assignment is changing a character. Ergo, shuffling is changing the contents. You might be able to get away with it, but I don't see why you would unnecessarily break the contract of the API, knowing the implementation could change later on, possibly breaking your code.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I agree that `std::random_shuffle` is changing the buffer contents. It is very questionable, however, that a character shuffle would affect `GetLength` in any way, especially as `GetLength` is required to work when the buffer remains unmodified.

Answer (score 0):

Convert `CString to std::string:-`

```
CString cs("Hello");
std::string s((LPCTSTR)cs);

NOTE:- BUT: std::string cannot always construct from a LPCTSTR. i.e. the code 
will fail for UNICODE   builds.
```

EDIT IN RESPONSE TO COMMENT

As std::string can construct only from LPSTR / LPCSTR, a programmer who uses VC++ 7.x or better can utilize conversion classes such as CT2CA as an intermediary.

```
CString cs ("Hello");
// Convert a TCHAR string to a LPCSTR
CT2CA pszConvertedAnsiString (cs);
// construct a std::string using the LPCSTR input
std::string strStd (pszConvertedAnsiString);
```

Use random_shuffle on s and then:-

```
CString cs1(s.c_str());
```

Comment: Note that you can use `std::basic_string<TCHAR>` to effectively get a `std::string` in narrow build and `std::wstring` in Unicode builds.